# V-Modell-XT: creating new project: "missing file V-Modell-XT.xml" (model files missing / installer is needed)

Tags: project-management

if downloaded from here (or a similar source):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fourever/files/

although described in the manual

http://sourceforge.net/p/fourever/code/HEAD/tree/projektassistent/trunk/docs/help/de/help.html#l24

we get an error:

- `startup-en.*` says `The chosen directory does not contain the V-Modell XT (missing file V-Modell-XT.xml). Please correct your choice.`
- `startup-de.*` says `Das angegebene Verzeichnis enthält nicht das V-Modell XT (zumindest nicht die benötigte Datei V-Modell-XT.xml. Bitte passen Sie Ihre Auswahl entsprechend an.`

Comment: should be moved to more appropriate site: http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me quite some research and contacting support to find this out ... This is due to the fact that the sourceforge repo only contains the tools, not the model itself (which is not very obvious).

That's why one should first install it via the official installer: http://www.cio.bund.de/DE/Architekturen-und-Standards/V-Modell-XT/vmodell_xt_node.html and then maybe update the tools via sourceforge binaries.